# How to not require email address for registration with ZfcUser

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

It is documented how to configure zfcUser to allow the username field on the registration form, and allow the user to login with either username or email.

However, I want to allow a user to register with username only, not require an email address for registration.

Is this configurable, or does it require overriding and re-implementing some fundamental zfcUser classes?

If so, any pointers where to start?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to override forms, there is a section in ZfcUser wiki to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser

you must change `'auth_identity_fields' => array( 'email' ),'enable_username' => false,`

to `'auth_identity_fields' => array( 'username' ),'enable_username' => true,`

> auth_identity_fields - Array value, specifies which fields a user can use as the 'identity' field when logging in. Acceptable values: username, email.

next overwrite RegisterFilter of ZfcUser and make email not required
to do this you must add zfcuser_register_form  key in module.config.php with your verison of Register Form and RegisterFilter

You probably need to change UserController.php as well to do this add zfcuser to module.config.php like this

```
'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'zfcuser' => 'Application\Controller\UserController',
        ),
 ),
```

UserController is your version of that controller
and of course you need your own UserEntity for all that (not sure is that true but it's better have one)

It's not complete solution but i hope it help little